# Trying to replace supersu with magisk in customrom.zip

Tags: android, sh, custom-rom

What if I want Magisk to be flashed with my custom Rom
but the Rom has update-binary which is a shell script and the updater-script is just a dummy file, how to make?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way :
first add this in update-binary

exec sh META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script "$@"

and then add this in updater-script

package_extract_dir("META-INF/ADD-ONS/magisk", "/tmp/magisk");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "unzip", "/tmp/magisk/magisk.zip", "META-INF/com/google/android/*", "-d", "/tmp/magisk");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "sh", "/tmp/magisk/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary", "dummy", "1", "/tmp/magisk/magisk.zip");
delete_recursive("/tmp/magisk");

and don't forget to add magisk.zip in the main Rom zip.